Separating Gamma in two independent functions
I've encountered a problem in my PhD. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions, tips, or comments you might have. The problem is
Let $\Gamma(s,x)$ be the incomplete gamma function. Given integers $n > m$, there exist functions $f,g$ such that
$$
\Gamma(n,m) = f(n)g(m) ?
$$
In other words, can we separate Gamma in two independent functions, in this specific case?

Is that an incomplete gamma function? You should probably explain your notation.

Welcome to MathOverflow. This was already posted about $2$ hours earlier on Math SE at Separating Gamma in two independent functions. Note that cross-posting, especially if it's done less than about a week later, is generally frowned on. Also, if you do post on another site, please at least include a link to the other post to help avoid duplication of efforts.

Yes, that's the incomplete gamma function, fixed now. Thank you all for the time helping me. I noticed there's a typo in the notation. I edited it on the other site, very sorry about the duplication thing. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4899440/separating-gamma-in-two-independent-functions

@curiosity96 : Do you have a response to the answer below?

$\newcommand\Ga\Gamma$If this factorization were true, we would get
$$1=\frac{f(3)g(1)\,f(4)g(2)}{f(4)g(1)\,f(3)g(2)}
=\frac{\Ga(3,1)\Ga(4,2)}{\Ga(4,1)\Ga(3,2)}=\frac{19}{16},$$
a contradiction.
So, your desired factorization cannot hold.
